# Having to use $(document).ready() multiple times in same script

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, document, ready

I have a script with the following structure:

```
Test = {

    CONSTANTS : {},
    VARIABLES : {},
    MARKUP : {},
    FUNCTIONS : {
        init : function () {

            // Access variable from different namespace
            var all_constants = DifferentNamespace.CONSTANTS; // WORKS
            var tester = DifferentNamespace.CONSTANTS.chunk_of_markup; // SAYS UNDEFINED
        }
    },
    init : function () {

        // Call real init() function

        $(document).ready(function () {

            Test.FUNCTIONS.init();
        });
    }

};

$(document).ready(function () {

    Test.init();
});
```

If I remove either of the `$(document).ready(..)` function calls, when I try to access a constant from a different namespace it is undefined; with both is works well.

As you can see I'm using two `init()` functions, one it just to neaten up the call to init because I have wrapped functions inside an additional object.

If I remove the function that is on the same level as CONSTANTS, VARIABLES etc and try to call the `init()` within Test.FUNCTIONS it still does not work.

Edit:

If i `console.log(all_constants)` I get the full object (with .chunk_of_markup) but if I `console.log(tester)` is get `undefined`. If i wrap tester i get `[]`

I should also note that the other namespace gets the markup from a seperate file.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Why are you using the ready function inside of your object method? It is already waiting for the ready event before init() is instantiated.

Comment: You are using developer tools to log the objects right? They don't log the object's state when logged... the state is fetched when you expand the object manually in console. To have reliable object logging (for plain objects at least), do something like `console.log( JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( obj ) ) );`

Comment: Is chunk of markup gotten with jQuery?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte As i explained, with just one or the other it does not work. I am looking for a reason why.

Comment: Because if the document is ready when you call `$(document).ready`, it will have the same effect as setting a timeout. jQuery uses this to make it asynchronous in all cases.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding this, but this fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/bvreH/

Comment: None of this stuff requires `$(document).ready` btw

Comment: Where and how is the other namespace set up? Is it done via a document ready handler that gets bound after the one you've shown that calls Test.init()? If so that might explain why you need another document ready in your init () - jQuery normally calls handlers for the same event in the order they're bound. (Though ready() is special in that the handler will be called even if bound after the event.)

Comment: FWIW: You don't need `$(document).ready()` inside `Test.init()` since `Test.init()` itself is called inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @MaratTanalin which is the point of the question! It works with both but not with one or the other. I added the second to check if it would fix it and it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two document ready doesn't make a difference here. You could have one document.ready and/or call Test.FUNCTIONS.init directly and all should work, and the fact that they are in different namespaces doesn't matter as well.

As for why you're getting undefined, I think it is probably because your **chunk_of_markup** variable is actually *undefined* at that point. My guess is that you're getting the value for it through AJAX and so the call is done asynchronously which means the DOM will be ready before it actually returns a value. When you use the Debugger then the value is evaluated at the point of time where you run the command so by then, the async call already returns successfully (it's a race condition, if you're fast enough and your AJAX is slow then you can still get undefined, and it's also why 2 ready functions happen to make it slow enough for the AJAX call to return but it's still unreliable).

In all cases, if my theory is correct, then you need to hook to the callback of the AJAX request rather that DOM ready event, this is the only place where you can guarantee that your variable is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Why not call the `function init()` in the document Handler itself.. I don't think that will lead to the same problems.. You can remove the `Test.init()` completely as it does not seem to do anything in here

```
Test = {
    CONSTANTS : {},
    VARIABLES : {},
    MARKUP : {},
    FUNCTIONS : {
        init : function () {

            // Access variable from different namespace
            var all_constants = DifferentNamespace.CONSTANTS; // WORKS
            var tester = DifferentNamespace.CONSTANTS.chunk_of_markup; // SAYS UNDEFINED
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    Test.FUNCTIONS.init();
});
```

Comment: Apologies, the question was worded quite poorly but I had already explained that this didn't work either